# Inline style with data attribute using JavaScript no jQuery, changing color

Tags: javascript, css

I have this piece element, which represents a coin in my connect four game, however, I want to change the background color of the coin using inline styling in JS. Is it possible to convert the CSS format to inline js styling? I have tried using getAttribute but don't think I am using right. Any suggestions would be helpful.

style.css:

```
.piece{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5%;
}

.piece[data-placed = "false"]{
  transform: translateY(-10vmin);
}
.piece[data-player = "1"]{                 //This is the element I want to inline style in my js file
  background-color: rgb(25, 0, 255);
}
.piece[data-player = "2"]{                  //This is the element I want to inline style in my js file
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

JS:

//Convert to inline styling

I have tried using the getattribute but doesn't change anything in my webpage.

Comment: what you mean by "convert to inline styling"? do you want to change background-color depending on data-player attribute?

Comment: So both players will input a color they desire, so by using inline styling in js I want to change the default color of the coins to what the players have provided. In other words, I want to style that attribute in my js file.

Comment: I have tried this :  piece.style.backgroundColor = "green", but I don't know how to target the data attribute data-player = "1".

Comment: so i posted the answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

just get the element by attribute selector and set its style attribute with background-color

```
  document
      .querySelector('.piece[data-player="1"]')
      .setAttribute('style', 'background-color: yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a HTML markup like:

```
<div class="piece" data-player="1"></div>
```

Changing its `data-` attribute's value should do it. So assuming you targeted an element with a `data-player="1"`:

```
element.dataset.player = "2"
```

Look the documentation for [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Or:

```
element.setAttribute("data-player", "2")
```